# Query will not give exact maximum salary result

Tags: oracle11g

It's a question I got this afternoon:

There a table contains ID, emp_Name,emp_mailid and Salary of Employees, get names of the first-highest salary employees, in oracle

here this is my table

```
id  emp_name    emp_mailid            salary
2   dinesh      dinesh@gmail.com       5000
3   ganesh      ganesh@gmail.com       6000
6   ramesh      ramesh@gmail.com       4500
10  suresh      suresh@gmail.com       10000
11  rajesh      rajesh@gmail.com       15000
15  kamesh      kamesh@gmail.com       16000
16  kamalesh    kamalesh@gmail.com     7800
19  neelash     neelash@gmail.com      12563
20  rajan       rajan@gmail.com        156231
22  vignesh     vignesh@gmail.com      45220
30  rubesh      rubesh@gmail.com       78000
31  john        john@gmail.com         6522
```

and this my query:

```
select *
  from
  (
    select
        salary
          ,dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) ranking
    from   test
  )
  where ranking = 1
```

when i execute this it shows maximum salary as 78000 but actually its wrong maximum salary is 156231

Can you suggest me a better query?

Answer (score 2):

If it shows you the maximum as 78000, it's probably because the salary column is varchar and not number.

try this:

```
select *
  from
  (
    select
        salary
          ,dense_rank() over (order by to_number(salary) desc) ranking
    from   test
  )
  where ranking = 1
```

Comment: now its working fine! very thanks!
but why varchar is not supporting?

Comment: @dineshdanny - if the column is `varchar` or `varchar2`, ordering by it is *alphabetical* order. In alphabetical order, the string '1000' comes before the string '92' (because the first character, '1', comes before '9'). This is one of the 100+ reasons the `salary` column **must** be of `number` data type. What were the developers drinking when they created the `salary` column as `varchar2`?